# How do I copy a column from one dataset into another?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

This is a fairly useful function that took a bit of juggling to figure out how to use without running into errors about the column already belonging to a dataset. Since I saw quite a few questions about doing this, I wanted to share the method I figured out.

Here's a functionalized version that takes just the source and recipient datasets, adds each column from the source and the values in turn:

```
protected DataSet AddColumns(DataSet ds, DataSet dt)
{
  foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Tables[0].Columns)
  {
    ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add(dc.ColumnName, dc.DataType);
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
      ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][dc.ColumnName] = dt.Tables[0].Rows[0][dc.ColumnName]; 
  }
  return ds;
}
```

Hopefully this will help somebody--it took a couple hours of looking at partial methods that didn't quite work to combine this into something nice and modular. :)

Comment: You need to copy the value of the column, not the column itself.

Comment: What would the syntax for that be? The line with the error should just be creating the column in the receiving table, not even copying the data yet. This also doesn't explain why when the Print_Data function is used it gets past the previous lines without a problem.